# What purpose serves the representation of arguments as ordered pairs?

Tags: logic, soft-question

Mathematical logic represents any arbitrary argument as an ordered pair $<\Gamma, \phi>$ where $\Gamma$ is the set of premises ( of the argument) and $\phi$ is the conclusion.

This representation allows us to state the identity conditions of 2 arguments , using this property of ordered pairs : $<a,b> = <c,d>$ iff $a=b$ and $c=d$.

What are the other benefits of this notation?

Is the complex symbol $<\Gamma, \phi>$ likely to be manipulated in a formal reasoning?

Comment: It is a simple way to define a mathematical object corresponding to the argument with premises in $\Gamma$ and conclusion $\phi$. It stands for both $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \phi$